# XPages datagrid not exiting from edit mode

Tags: datagrid, dojo, xpages

I use dojo.grid.datagrid

If the DataGrid contains lots of rows(example 200) and to scroll, it does not work exit from edit mode cell. Do know what the problem is?

upd: Or maybe someone knows how to use dgrid / gridx in xPages, becouse i found next big bug - encoding after save rest service :(

Comment: I recommend reading the excellent series from Brad Balassaitas on using Dojo grids in XPages: http://xcellerant.net/dojo-grids-in-xpages/ From this (and your previous) question, I suspect that this series contains much information that will simplify what you're attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But Mr. Brad Balassaitas make ​​a mistake. Reason for error not AutoHeigh. Reason - rowsPerPage. The error occurs when the next page is loaded. For example, if we have 200 rows, and the parameter rowPerPage set 200, the error will not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah! I solved it! :) Error in FileStore.js(extlib). Add this on onClientLoad. I change "!!error code"

```
restViewItemFileService._processResponse = function(requestObject, data) {
    this._items.splice(0, this._items.length); // !!error code -> this.close();
    this._start = requestObject.start;

    //TODO: clear identity?     
    dojo.forEach(data.items, function(entry, idx) {
        var item = {storeRef:this, attributes:entry};
        var id = item.attributes[this._identity]
                                 var pending = this._pendings[id]
                                                              if(pending) {
                                                                  for (var s in pending.modAttrs[s]) {
                                                                      this.item.attributes[s] = pending.modAttrs[s]
                                                                  }
                                                              }
        this._byIdentity[id] = item;
        this._items.push(item);
    }, this);

    this._topLevelEntries = data['@toplevelentries'];
    this.onData(requestObject, data);
    this._finishResponse(requestObject);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I just did some testing and I believe I'm seeing the same thing. It seems to be fine to edit and save as I move through the grid. I can scroll down as needed and save changes. However, when I scroll back up and put a cell in edit mode, it doesn't save the changes -- it immediately reverts to the original value. And sometimes it just leaves the cell in edit mode.

I would agree that it seems to be an issue with memory management. If I set the rowsPerPage to a number that will keep all rows in memory, it appears (with very limited testing) that I can scroll up and down and make changes and they're all saved.

I don't have a solution at the moment, but what I would suggest in lieu of a perfect solution is to find a way to set rowsPerPage to a number greater than the amount of rows that will be displayed in the grid. If there's too much data for that to be feasible, then the approach I would take is to provide filtering on the grid to keep the maximum number of rows displayed much lower and then it won't be as much of a performance hit to set the rowsPerPage to a sufficient amount.

If I come across a better solution, I'll come back and post it here.